# Change style of placemark after clicking in layer list Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

Google Earth: Is it possible to change style of Placemark after clicking on this Placemark in Layer List. By default, if you click on Placemark in Layer List, Balooon (popup) will be opened over Placemark. I want also change style.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KML allows two sets of styles to be defined for a given Placemark using a [StyleMap](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#stylemap).

StyleMap allows you to define a default style (normal) and a highlight style which is active when the user hovers over (aka mouses over) the feature on the map.

```
  <Style id="normalState">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/A.png</href>
        </Icon>            
      </IconStyle>
  </Style>

  <Style id="highlightState">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.3</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/B.png</href>
        </Icon>           
      </IconStyle>
  </Style>

  <StyleMap id="styleMapExample">
    <Pair>
      <key>normal</key>
      <styleUrl>#normalState</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
    <Pair>
      <key>highlight</key>
      <styleUrl>#highlightState</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
  </StyleMap>
```

A simple example can be found here that changes the icon and its size when you hover over it:
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Style/inline-stylemap.kml

Comment: I now this approach with StyleMap, but when you double click on placemark in Layer list, style is not highlighted.

Comment: Google defines that the highlight style appears when "user mouses over the icon in Google Earth". Does not say what happens wrt Style when user selects it (e.g. via the places panel) but one can argue that selecting it should use the highlighted style.

Comment: So, its not possible to change style after clicking Placemark in my Places. Thanks